# Canonical way to define common constants in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm developing a couple of Vue apps using single file components. I find quite a few of my components require common config information, for example an object containing delivery methods which I might define like this:

```
const DeliveryMethods = {
  DELIVERY: "Delivery",
  CARRIER: "Carrier",
  COLLATION: "Collation",
  CASH_AND_CARRY: "Cash and carry"
}
```

What is the cannonical way to make that available to my components? At the moment, I have done it with a file 'config.js', as below:

```
export default {

  DeliveryMethods: {
    DELIVERY: "Delivery",
    CARRIER: "Carrier",
    COLLATION: "Collation",
    CASH_AND_CARRY: "Cash and carry"
  }

}
```

In my components where I need it, I have `import config from 'src/config.js'`, and where I want to use one of these, I'll refer to e.g., `config.DeliveryMethods.CASH_AND_CARRY`. This seems to me rather long-winded and repetitive, though, and I'd prefer to be able to use just `DeliveryMethods.CASH_AND_CARRY` instead of `config.DeliveryMethods.CASH_AND_CARRY`.

What is the canonical way to based on  [js lint](http://www.jslint.com/help.html) and/or the  [jquery style guide](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/)? Are there any other authorities to consider?

Comment: If you just want `DeliveryMethods.CASH_AND_CARRY` why not just export the POJO without the extra scoping of `DeliveryMethods: {...}` and just export the `{DELIVERY: "Delivery", ...}` portion; Then `import DeliveryMethods from "./src/config.js"` ?

Answer (score 67):

`delivery-methods/index.js`

```js
const DELIVERY = "Delivery"
const CARRIER = "Carrier"
const COLLATION = "Collation"
const CASH_AND_CARRY = "Cash and carry"
    
export default {
  DELIVERY: DELIVERY,
  CARRIER: CARRIER,
  COLLATION: COLLATION,
  CASH_AND_CARRY: CASH_AND_CARRY
}
```

Usage

```js
import DeliveryMethods from './path/to/delivery-methods'

console.log(DeliveryMethods.CARRIER)
```

Or:

`config.js`

```js
export default Object.freeze({
  DELIVERY: "Delivery",
  CARRIER: "Carrier",
  COLLATION: "Collation",
  CASH_AND_CARRY: "Cash and carry"
})
```

Usage:

```js
import DeliveryMethods from './path/to/delivery-methods'

console.log(DeliveryMethods.CARRIER)
```

Comment: Thanks, this and subhaze's comment pointed me in the right direction. DeliveryMethods isn't the only constant I'd want to use, so `export default` doesn't work if I want to have all my constants in a single file for ease of maintenance. What I've done is this:

Comment: is there any other way then importing file in each and every vue file where we want to use that constant ?

Comment: Is the OR variant correct? How can you import DeliveryMethods, when the config.js defines no DeliveryMethods?

Answer (score 31):

Thanks, this and subhaze's comment pointed me in the right direction. DeliveryMethods isn't the only constant I'd want to use, so `export default` doesn't work if I want to have all my constants in a single file for ease of maintenance. What I've done is this:

```
export const DeliveryMethods = {
    DELIVERY: "Delivery",
    CARRIER: "Carrier",
    COLLATION: "Collation",
    CASH_AND_CARRY: "Cash and carry"
};
```

In my components I have `import {DeliveryMethods} from 'src/config.js'`, which allows me to simply use e.g. `DeliveryMethods.COLLATION`. I can export/import any number of constants clearly and simply. Still feeling my way round Javascript modules!

LATER: Following WaldemarIce's suggestion, I have changed this to:

```
export const DeliveryMethods = Object.freeze({
    DELIVERY: "Delivery",
    CARRIER: "Carrier",
    COLLATION: "Collation",
    CASH_AND_CARRY: "Cash and carry"
});
```

That works better.

Comment: Try what happens if you try to redefine `DeliveryMethods.DELIVERY = 'bla'`.

Comment: Well, I know that I can mutate the properties of an object even though the object itself has been declared via `const`, so the object isn't immutable. Your declaration of the constants themselves via `const` prior to assigning them to properties of the object would guard against that. But it's a little more verbose than I want to do it that way, and I'm thinking of the way I've done it as a kind of convention - title case object name with uppercase properties means it's an object with constants, so don't tamper!

Comment: Ok, I understand, but why not to use the second option with Object.freeze()? It is not so verbose and it simulate constants, you cant change the properties of the freezed object.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed my answer now to use Object.freeze() as you suggest. Best of both worlds.

Comment: Hmm ... I tried your suggestion, and it does not work for me? the DeliveryMethods object ends up being undefined. How do you refer to it in the Vue component?