# Where to declare non-changing data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like, in a Vue component, to use some data that does not change. The following code does not work:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3]
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="number in numbers">
    {{number}}
  </div>
</div>
```

It fails with the error

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "numbers" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

The messages indicates that I tried to use `numbers` in a "reactive" way. In my case, however, the data is expected not to change (highlighted by the `const` declaration).

I can of course push `numbers` into the instance, and this works:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    numbers: [1, 2, 3]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="number in numbers">
    {{number}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I feel however a bit uncomfortable with this, my understanding of "reactive" being that `data` is a place for information that changes (and the change is reflected in the DOM).

**What is the correct way to use constant (non-changing) data in Vue? (specifically where to declare it)**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to define common constants in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47597384/best-way-to-define-common-constants-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All data the template need to access **has to be** on Vue instance (`data` or `computed`) (you can imagine every access in template is prepend with `this.`) and there is no way around it
2. Making you data part of Vue instance make it reactive. Usually its not a problem but it might in case you have huge amount of data you know will never change (perf). In which case you can use a tip from [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) and apply `Object.freeze()` which makes whole object "non-reactive" but also unable to change in any way
3. You can fine-tune the data using [this tip](https://jsfiddle.net/Akryum/q8wu5aem/) from Akryum (Vue core member) to create objects with some properties reactive and some non-reactive (Applies only to Vue2 which uses `Object.defineProperty` to make data reactive. I'll try to update for Vue3 proxies later..)

Option 2. is probably best approach for your use case...